# Getting WebRTC built into TOR

Tags: configuration, plugin

**Situation:**

I have been trying to get WebRTC onto the TOR Browser. **I Know** this might sound stupid at first, I explained my reasons on why I wanted to do this in my previous post: [Getting WebRTC on TOR](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14660/getting-webrtc-on-tor?noredirect=1#comment16304_14660)

**Current Progress:**

After no luck with finding already made plugins, I decided to try to build it into TOR myself. I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu btw (Xenial 16.04). What I have done so far is:

- Download a fresh version of TOR but without installing it
- Download the version of firefox that the previous TOR version was based off of (firefox 45.9.0), only downloaded, didn't install.
- Located relevant WebRTC files in the firefox:

  - firefox-sdk/include/mozilla/media/webrtc/WebrtcGlobal.h

    this file has a few `#include ...`s at the top, which are files that are also located within the firefox downloaded bundle, and some of these refer to other files, and so on.

**Questions:**

- If I copy all the files that are related to the WebRTC file `WebrtcGlobal.h` would that compose all the necessary files in order to implement WebRTC into tor? If I need more please let me know which, and if I don't need all the ones included, which ones are the only ones I need?
- After having the right files, where in TOR should I include them? Do I need to modify certain configurations, like `media.peerconnection.enabled=false` into `true`, amongst others?
- Is there anything else I would need to do? **As you can see**, I am kind of learning as I go along, any and all feedback is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [Ways to Build Tor Browser](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowser/Hacking#WaystoBuildTorBrowser) and [#8178](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8178).

You'd need to edit the build process to not use the `--disable-webrtc` flag. Simply copying the files will not be sufficient, since they are built into firefox and the various libraries at compile time you'd need to compile a new copy of Tor Browser, from source, with the features enabled.

Yes, `media.peerconnection.enabled` would need to be set to `true`.